# Keyboard & Mouse VS Xbox 360 controller VS PS3 controller

Tags: xbox-360, pc, ps3, controllers, keyboard

I recently started to game on PC.
Right now, I already have a keyboard, a (gaming) mouse and a fake PS2 controller with an USB adapter. I am just an average gamer that plays games in their free time. I grew up with PlayStation consoles. (PS1, 2 and PSP)

I don't have a problem with game compatibility as I use MotionInJoy to convert DirectInput to XInput.

But my controllers' shoulder buttons really bug me, as I have to push them in really hard.

Right now I have some spare money so I can buy a better controller.

What do you think that fits best to me?
PS3 controller or XBox 360 controller?
Or should I just stay with the keyboard and mouse?
Can you give me some examples too if you can, about why which one is better?
Should i stay with PlayStation or try an XBox controller?

Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: It depends on the game you play (FPS, racing, RPG).
For my part, I prefer using the keyboard and the mouse to play FPS/TPS and RPG games. I think you're more precise with this set. It also depends on what you're used to play with. 
Racing games are better with the joystick IMO

Comment: I don't think we can answer that question for you as it's a matter of play style and preferences. You'll have to figure it out for yourself what you like best. Just don't play shooter games with a controller.

Comment: you're right thats it, so i need at least two of them(keyboard mouse) and joystick,.
now which one is better?
xbox joystick or ps3 joystick?

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't allow recommendations or opinion-based questions. However, if you can, you should prefer the PS4 or Xbox One controller over the PS3 or Xbox 360 ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use a GamePad or a Keyboard only you can decide as it is a matter of which games you play (e.g. most people like playing Racing Games with Controller) and personal preferance.

However, if you don't mind that the PS3 Controller doesn't have native support, in my experience the PS3 one is slightly better because of the d-pad (the rest is pretty much ex aequo) which you pretty much only need for Retro Games.

IMHO this can't be answered objectively as there are too many opinion-based 
factors.

EDIT: The XBOX 360 Controller doesn't have Preassure Sensitive Buttons, only the analog sticks and triggers are preassure sensitive, making certain games hard to play.

Comment: and that's it, i just asked bout your opinion,
i grow up with playstation console(psx,ps2) should i just stay with ps3 controller or try move to xbox controller?

Comment: As said, I think the PS3 Controller is a bit better, however unless you are playing Retro-games that require the d-pad you probably wouldn't even notice a big difference. The only real reason for using XBOX Controllers is because they have native support.

Comment: thankyou, this is what i want to know,.
1 more question, is xbox360 trigger has pressure sensitive?
like if i full press then it will accelerate more than if i just press some than it just half accelerate ?

Comment: That is actually a valid concern which I forgot to cover, I updated my answer

Comment: anyway, did ps joystick has mode pressure sensitive button sensor than xbox? and works on pc(using motioninjoy)?

Comment: Yes, the Playstation Controller does have preassure sensitive buttons, how well motionjoy utilizes that I don't know, but as far as I know it should work fine. However, I don't think there is any Computer game that utilizes preassure sensitive buttons. It usually only uses preassure sensitive analog sticks.